# How Scala knows what collection implementation to use?

Tags: scala, constructor, scala-collections

```
val set1 = Set(1,2,3)
```

or

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3)
```

Can you describe a precise mechanics behind the construction of such objects?

In **Java** we need *HashSet* or *LinkedList* to construct the object.

Here we see traits used with apply method?

Where IS this apply method?

Something with implicits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traits can have companion objects.  So when you call `Set(1, 2, 3)`, you're actually calling the `apply` method on the companion object `Set`.  For example, you can see the `Set` companion object documentation [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set$), and its source code [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L1).

Each collection type's companion object has a default implementation that is instantiated with use of `apply`.  In fact, the collection type's companion objects all extend from the abstract class [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion), which encapsulates this behavior.

Here is an image of the Scala immutable collections type hierarchy.  An arrow from `A` to `B` means `B` extends `A`, a dotted arrow means `B` is implicitly viewable as a `A`, and a bold line means that the `apply` method on the companion object of `A` returns an instance of `B`.

[image: Scala immutable collections]

So, for example, when you call `Iterable(1, 2, 3)`, you get a `List`, since there are bold lines from `Iterable` to `Seq` to `LinearSeq` to `List`.  You can read more about the Scala collections type hierarchy (including the mutable versions) [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html).

When coming from Java, this may be surprising, but it actually makes a lot of sense.  When you're instantiating an `Set`, for example, you might not care what the actual implementation is and in fact just want all the guarantees of the `Set` type contract, and can trust the language to pick an implementation.

You happened to use `Set` in your question, which is slightly more complicated.  `Sets` with fewer than 5 elements have special implementations for efficiency.  So the bold arrow in the above diagram  shows only the *usual* case (for sufficiently large `Sets`).  For example:

```
Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asInstanceOf[HashSet[Int]] // Works as expected
Set(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[HashSet[Int]] // Doesn't work!
Set(1, 2, 3).asInstanceOf[collection.immutable.Set.Set3[Int]] // Set3 is the special implementation of sets with example 3 elements.
```

As a final note on working with collections, using the REPL here is really useful in figuring out the default implementations of the collection traits (without needing to refer to the diagram).  For example, here we can see that the `Iterable` companion object constructs a `List`, as expected:

```
Iterable(1, 2, 3)
>>> Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: According to the pic, Set's default is HashSet, List's default is List.
Is it true?
That mean val set1 = Set(1,2,3) constructs HashSet?
That mean val list1 = List(1,2,3) constructs List?

Comment: That's basically correct, and that's what those arrow are meant to signify in the diagram.  `Set` is a little bit more complicated since, as seen in the linked source code, it has special implementations for sets with fewer than 4 elements.  So `Set(1, 2, 3, 4)` returns a `HashSet`, but `Set(1, 2, 3)` returns a `Set3` special implementation, which I believe is private.

Comment: I mark your answer as final, however, I understand, that the deep dive is required to get into details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`List` has a [companion object](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/companion-object.html) which has the `apply` defined as:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

**More in depth**

So, now we are left with the question of where does the `xs` varargs go? This essentially boils down to a [TraversableOnce](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala), which has its `toList` calling

```
  def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A @uV]]): Col[A @uV] = {
    val b = cbf()
    b ++= seq
    b.result()
  }
```

which leads to `CanBuildFrom`...which is not a simple answer - so I will simply [point you in the right direction on that one](http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/08/getting-to-know-canbuildfrom-without-phd.html)

Comment: Can anybody verify that the varargs falls into TraversableOnce. I believe I traced that one down appropriately, but wouldn't mind verification

Answer (score 0):

`List` has a [companion object](http://daily-scala.blogspot.co.il/2009/09/companion-object.html).

According to [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), there's a companion object factory:

> def companion: GenericCompanion[List]
>
> The factory companion object that builds instances of class List.

Here are some ways to use the companion explicitly: [what is the use case for scala List's companion function returning GenericCompanion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568609/what-is-the-use-case-for-scala-lists-companion-function-returning-genericcompan)

Comment: It doesn't [explains companion internals](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L457), though (what is SeqFactory, how varargs are turned into List, and so on).

Comment: Answer me more basic question:

When I do val list1 = List(1,2,3) what implementation is actually used?

the trait itself? without any implementation?

I've seen a CanBuildFrom and SetBuilder and etc...

But from them I got an impression, that List itself initiated, not any of its sub classes. Is it true?